# Asserting equality of two armadillo cx_mat matrices using CPPUNIT

Tags: c++, cppunit, armadillo

I'm new to CPPUNIT. I have generated a matrix A of type cx_mat(complex double) using armadillo library and I have a reference(expected) matrix B of the same type. Please suggest a way to arrest using the matrices A and B and a delta(tolerance) of say 0.0001 in one-shot WITHOUT looping through the entire matrix.

If the above is not possible and if the only alternative is to use the CPPUNIT_ASSERT_DOUBLES_EQUAL_MESSAGE method in a for loop, then please provide me the correct syntax and header files for using the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with

```
bool Arma_test::Is_close(arma::cx_mat& X, arma::cx_mat& Y, double tol)
{
    // abs returns a mat type then max checks columns and returns a row_vec
    // max used again will return the biggest element in the row_vec
    bool close(false);
    if(arma::max(arma::max(arma::abs(X-Y))) < tol)
    {
        close = true;
    }
    return close;
}
```

See [Armadillo Docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html).

Comment: the following is more compact `arma::accu(abs(X-Y))`.  see the docs for [accu()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#accu)

Comment: `arma::accu` would also do the job but is not equivalent code, it sums all of the elements.

Comment: I think `arma::norm(X-Y, "inf") < tol` (infinity norm) might be the best way. See [norm](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#norm) .

Answer (score 3):

You can now use the [approx_equal](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#approx_equal) function.